# Using previous data in Bayesian change point detection

Tags: bayesian, model-comparison, change-point

I'm interested in the detection of a **single** change point. I have phase I data, $X_{-n},\ldots, X_{-1}$, and I when subsequent observation arrive I want to find if their distribution has changed (either in mean or variance).

There is a plethora of methods, some summarized here: [An evaluation of change point detection algorithms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.06222.pdf). In which it seems the method suggested by Adams and MacKay [Bayesian Online Chane Point Detection](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.3742.pdf) seems favorable. This leads me to two questions:

1. How to incorporate the data from phase I into the Bayesian method. I tried letting the algorithm run on $X_{-n},\ldots, X_{i}$, but it sometimes detect change in the phase I data. The second option I tried is to update the posterior according to the phase I data, but then it never detects any change later.
2. Is there a non-parametric change-point detection method (detecting change in distribution, not necessarily in mean and variance)? Preferable if it is available in python.